# C++ Vector Calculator

Tags: c++

So I decided to take a challenge and make an 'infinite' calculator using vectors
The goal of my calculator is to get user input and add/sub/mult/div all the variables he enters, not just 2 variables like most simple calculators. I got most of the code done except for the point where it asks the users input. I don't only want to add 2 variables together and get the result, I want to get as many variables as the user enters and then do the required math to get the result.

The place where I need help is in the user_input() function.
I wrote this line to give you an idea of what I want:

```
 std::cin >> v.push_back(user_value) >> user_symbol >> v.push_back(user_value);
```

but, as you can see, the compiler spits out errors.

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back<int, std::allocator<int> >((*(const value_type*)(& user_value)))'|
```

Also, I know that this isn't the right way to get more than 2 values from the user since i'm only getting 2 values but I'd like for my program to receive more than 2 values..

P.S. still fairly new to C++, if you have any tips you'd like to share feel free :)

Here's the full source code:

```
// main.cpp
// calculator using vectors

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

typedef std::vector<int>::size_type vc_size;

int add(std::vector<int> v_add);
int sub(std::vector<int> v_sub);
int mult(std::vector<int> v_mult);
int div(std::vector<int> v_div);
void p_info();
void user_info();

int main(){
    return 0;
}

int add(std::vector<int> v_add){
    vc_size vector_size = v_add.size();
    int add_result = v_add[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < vector_size; i++){
        add_result += v_add[i];
    }

    return add_result;
}

int sub(std::vector<int> v_sub){
    vc_size vector_size = v_sub.size();
    int sub_result = v_sub[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < vector_size; i++){
        sub_result -= v_sub[i];
    }

    return sub_result;
}

int mult(std::vector<int> v_mult){
    vc_size vector_size = v_mult.size();
    int mult_result = v_mult[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < vector_size; i++){
        mult_result *= v_mult[i];
    }

    return mult_result;
}

int div(std::vector<int> v_div){
    vc_size vector_size = v_div.size();
    int div_result = v_div[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < vector_size; i++){
        div_result /= v_div[i];
    }

    return div_result;
}

void p_info(){
    std::cout << "Vector calculating program" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Calculate: ";
}

void user_info(){
    char user_symbol;
    int user_value;
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::cin >> v.push_back(user_value) >> user_symbol >> v.push_back(user_value);

    switch(user_symbol){
        case '+':
            std::cout << add(v);
            break;
        case '-':
            std::cout << sub(v);
            break;
        case '*':
            std::cout << mult(v);
            break;
        case '/':
            std::cout << div(v);
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: "but, as you can see, the compiler spits out errors."- my eyes are failing me because I see no errors in your post. Also you mention `user_input()` but all I see is `user_info()`; to confirm, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: _'... but, as you can see, the compiler spits out errors.'_ I can't spot any error n your question! Would you mind editing and telling us these?

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin >> v.push_back(user_value)`

You can't do this.

You must do this instead

```
std::cin >> user_value;
v.push_back(user_value)
```

Comment: Okay thanks, and how can I go about getting as many user variables possible until I press enter?

Comment: @Porky You don't need _many_ `user_value` it's just used temporarily for input. The _many_ values are stored n the `vector<>`. May be it's the better option to use `std::getline()` and parse the values from a `std::istringstream` instead of directly reading from `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get as many variables as the user enters and then do the required math to get the result.

How do you want the user to signal stop? You can easily achieve this with a loop:

```
while(true) {
    std::cin >> user_value1 >> user_symbol >> user_value2;
    v.push_back(user_value1);
    v.push_back(user_value2);
    stop_condition...
    //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Yep, but if I wanted it to be "x + y + z" or even "x + y + z + a" and not just "x + y" ?

Comment: @Porky Yes, but add a stop condition, like "q" or it will keep asking for numbers